# Automatically transfer Blog post (rss) in Facebook, Twitter

Tags: facebook, windows-services, rss, twitter

Any APIs or application that could be used to pull a RSS feed and put it on a configured Facebook, Twitter, ... account ?

Kind of a [Add This](http://addthis.com/) but in something like a Windows Service

Thanks !

Patrick

Comment: I'm pretty sure Facebook has a feature that automatically does this for you. Check in the "Notes" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Twitterfeed](http://twitterfeed.com/) will post your RSS feed into Twitter and Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

Better than twitter feed is [engator - rss to twitter and facebook](http://engator.com)

Answer (score 0):

Check TweetMiner that does the job for [Twitter](http://tweetminer.net/).